# rails test calls the wrong controller which shares the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

Below is 1 unit test which I am running. Calling the file `rail test test/functional/api/field_notes_controller_test.rb` works perfectly.

```
class FieldNotesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
    tests Api::FieldNotesController

    test "upload file with wrong proj id" do
        post "create",params:{token: "abc",'format'=>'json',"bogus" => "data"}
```

And the following controller is covered.

```
module Api
    class FieldNotesController < Api::ParentController
        ...
```

But when all tests are run `rails test` something happens to the router and instead of testing the controller shown above, it does a POST of the controller below. They share the same name, but are on different modules.

```
class FieldNotesController < ApplicationController
    ...
```

How can I diagnose/solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to name your test class and ensure it's in a folder named api (depending on your controller setup - the folder structures in your tests need to match the ones in your app)

`class Api::FieldNotesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase`